# URL reconstructor service - open to any ideas

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, request

I own two domains, [RiverSparrow](http://riversparrow.co.uk) and rs.co. What I want to do is use the short domain as a parallel to the main domain, without having to upload the same file structure on each server. So what I would like to do is be able to catch any request that comes in to rs.co, preferably using just one file (or a combination - but the point is that I don't want to have to upload the same file to every folder on the server), then reconstruct the URL as before but substituting rs.co for riversparrow.co.uk. The URL formatting I can do - it's the catching any request no matter the URL that I have problems with.
I'm open to any suggestions. I have some notion that it may need htaccess, which is fine, but feel free to do it in any language (though server-side not PHP will need installation).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Web server configuration. Ask on [Webmasters.se]

Comment: be careful if you care how google will index you. as duplicate content on different domains may be penalised

Comment: @MikeW: I have. I figure it's part of both, as I'm also asking for a programmatic solution, which is SO's purpose to attempt to provide.

Comment: If you have asked this elsewhere, please provide the URL here (in the comments or in the question) so we can see if it has already been answered prior to answering.

Comment: @CaolanEvans This is a simple web server configuration task - no programming required. If you want a programmatic solution you need to be very much more specific as your question is too broad as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go is obviously to assign both domains to the same virtual webhost - nothing more to do.

If you do need to go down the described route, take a look at custom 404 handlers - basically you

- leave the complete server empty apart from a single script, that does **not** exist on the other server (e.g. my404hander.php)
- You dedicate this script as custom 404 handler in Apache

This leads to this control flow:

- A client requests `/some/url`
- This is not found (server is basically empty), leading to 404 error
- Your custom handler is invoked
- it is now able to construct the coreseponding URL and do whatever it seems it should, e.g. send a redirect

Comment: The 404 handler option seems viable. I'll have a look at virtual webhost but I doubt my host would let it get through.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to Eugen’s answer, I would rather suggest using [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive … “abusing” the 404 handler feels dirty.

Plus you would not have to do any “URL reconstruction” – because apache will do it for you.

`Redirect permanent / http://riversparrow.co.uk` should do it.

Comment: Will this redirect for any URL requested or just the path / specified?

Comment: Does the documentation page I linked to really leave that question unanswered …?

Comment: Server is down or unavailable because I can't get at it. Wouldn't have asked if I could have found out.

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect